# How to run a migration for a specific app in Django

Tags: django, migration, migrate

**What I need**

I added an new app in my project and a separate database for it. I have created the Models for that app and now I need to migrate this models in this separate database

app name - authors_app

database name - authors

**My code**

```
python3 manage.py makemigrations authors_app
```

It creates the 0001_initial.py file which contains only models from my authors_app. So this step is OK

```
python3 manage.py migrate authors_app 0001_initial --database=authors
```

And this command runs not only my migrations from authors_app, but also migrations from my other app

**Problem**

I need to migrate only migrations from authors_app. But the migrate command runs the migrations from all apps. I have 58 migrations in my other app. And this command runs them all into the new database ...

**Question**

How can I run migrate for only authors_app

**Update**

Inside my authors_app Models I use one model from another app

```
from tibrains_app.models import Language

class AuthorLanguage(models.Model):

    author = models.OneToOneField(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    native_list = models.ManyToManyField(Language, related_name='author_native_languages')
    all_list = models.ManyToManyField(Language, related_name='author_all_languages')
    writing_list = models.ManyToManyField(Language, related_name='author_writing_languages')
```

And inside my 0001_initial file I have a dependencies

```
dependencies = [
        ('tibrains_app', '0058_book_history_period'),
    ]
```

Could this cause the problem?

Comment: Your command seems correct to me, this may be due to migrations dependencies.

Comment: And how can I solve this problem?
I have 58 migrations in my other app. And this command runs them all into the new database ...

Comment: If you're sure your migration doesn't depend on any other migration, you can set the `dependencies` attribute to an empty list.

Comment: Inside my authros_app model I use one model from another app

Comment: I've updated my question. I've added info about dependencies and about model from another app. Could this cause the problem?

Comment: Yes, this is why the other migrations are executed. Moreover, Django does not allow relations between different databases, you might want to change your setup/migration. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/multi-db/.